# Set taxonomy slug as taxonomy title

Tags: slug

With post types I can easily set the slug to be always identical to the post type title.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'prefix_wp_insert_post_data' );
function prefix_wp_insert_post_data( $data ) {
    $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] );
    return $data;
}
```

But with taxonomies I'm rather stuck.
I've been reading up on the `editable_slug` and `wp_insert_post` filters and this trac ticket https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9073, but still unsure on how to accomplish the same.

Could someone perhaps point me into an even more novice direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms are inserted with `wp_insert_term()` and updated with `wp_update_term()`.

There's the `pre_insert_term` filter, where one can modify the term's *name* but not the *slug*.

If we dig further, we see that both functions call `sanitize_term()` that again calls the `sanitize_term_field()` function.

There we have  various filters available.

### Example #1

Here's one combination if we want to target the *category* taxonomy during **inserts**:

```
/**
 * Set the category slug as the sanitize category name during category inserts
 */
add_filter( 'pre_category_name', function( $name )
{
    add_filter( 'pre_category_slug', function( $slug ) use ( $name )
    {       
        return $name ? sanitize_title( $name ) : $slug;
    } );

    return $name;
} );
```

### Example #2

Let's instead wrap it inside the `pre_insert_term` hook and make sure it only runs once.

```
/**
 * Set the term's slug as the sanitized term's name when inserting category terms
 */
add_filter( 'pre_insert_term', function( $term, $taxonomy )
{
    add_filter( 'pre_term_slug', function( $value ) use ( $term, $taxonomy )
    {       
        if( ! did_action( 'pre_term_slug' ) && $term && 'category' === $taxonomy )
            $value = sanitize_title( $term );

        return $value;
    } );

    return $term;
}, 10, 2 );
```

To target the term's update, we can use the `edit_category_name` and `edit_category_slug` filters, or in general the `edit_term_name` and `edit_term_slug` filters.

Hopefully you can adjust it and test it further.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in detail. This definitely gives me something to work with.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with the project  @CorvanNoorloos